# Draw two pointlines in a histogram (gnuplot)?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw two pointsline in a histogram by gnuplot, The result chart is not exactly what I wanted. Actually, I want points in two pointlines(the pink one and the lightgreen one) align the center of two types of pillars, so the lightgreen one keeps still, while the pink one move a little to the right, just like the black one I have drawn.

the 'test.dat' is as follow:

```
1   10  15  8   22 
2   11  19  7   21
3   9   14  7   19
4   10  21  8   23
5   9   17  9   21
```

and the 'plt' file:

```
set style data histogram
unset key 
set yrange[0:12]
set y2range[0:25]

plot "test.dat" using 2:xticlabel(1) axis x1y1,\
"test.dat" using 3:xticlabel(1) axis x1y2 with linespoints,\
"test.dat" using 4:xticlabel(1) axis x1y1,\
"test.dat" using 5:xticlabel(1) axis x1y2 with linespoints
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on [this contribution](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/plot-histograms-using-boxes.html) which uses boxes instead of a histogram. The benefit is that, you know exactly where those boxes are placed, which you can exploit for the line plot.

Here's the code:

```
dx=1.
n=2.
total_box_width_relative=0.25
gap_width_relative=0.1
d_width=(gap_width_relative+total_box_width_relative)*dx/n  
set boxwidth total_box_width_relative/n relative  
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder

plot "test.dat" u ($1):2 w boxes lc rgb"green" notitle,\    
     "test.dat" u ($1+d_width):4 w boxes lc rgb"red" notitle,\
     "test.dat" u ($1):3 w linespoints notitle,\              
     "test.dat" u ($1+d_width):5 w linespoints notitle        

set yrange [0:15]
replot
```

Some explanations to the code:

- The `dx` should be selected according to your data file, otherwise the spacing of the boxes will be off.
- The number of data-sets for the boxes is given by `n`
- The `total_box_width_relative` and `gap_width_relative` control the axial with and spacing of the boxes
- the two `set ...` commands control the appearance of your boxes
- within the plot command you now have to separate: You call one set of boxes and lines with the original 1st column data: `($1)`, however, for the second set of boxes and the corresponding line, you choose your defined axial offset: `($1+d_width)` - this will ensure that the data points from the line plot will align with the boxes
- it may be necessary to include a `set yrange` command

The plot will look like this:

[image]

**Note**
I changed the data for the line plots with regard to the data you provided. This was done only to bring the points closer to the boxes and illustrate the effect.