# Gnuplot Histogram Cluster (Bar Chart) with One Line per Category

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, bar-chart

### Histogram Cluster / Bar Chart

I'm trying to generate the following **histogram cluster** out of this data file with **gnuplot**, where each **category** is represented **in a separate line** per year in the data file:

```
# datafile
year   category        num_of_events
2011   "Category 1"    213
2011   "Category 2"    240
2011   "Category 3"    220
2012   "Category 1"    222
2012   "Category 2"    238
...
```

[image: desired histogram cluster]

But I don't know how to do it with one line per category. I would be glad if anybody has got an idea how to do this with gnuplot.

### Stacked Histogram Cluster / Stacked Bar Chart

Even better would be a **stacked** histogram cluster like the following, where the **stacked sub categories** are represented by **separate columns** in the datafile:

```
# datafile
year   category        num_of_events_for_A    num_of_events_for_B
2011   "Category 1"    213                    30
2011   "Category 2"    240                    28
2011   "Category 3"    220                    25
2012   "Category 1"    222                    13
2012   "Category 2"    238                    42
...
```

[image: desired stacked histogram cluster]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: These are really just vertical bar plots.  I don't call something a histogram unless I have an array of items and the code has to bin and count the items.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327576/how-do-you-plot-bar-charts-in-gnuplot

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I've modified the title accordingly.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451384/draw-two-pointlines-in-a-histogram-gnuplot/17454718#17454718) is of interest to you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After some research, I came up with two different solutions.

### Required: Splitting the data file

Both solutions require splitting up the data file into several files categorized by a column. Therefore, I've created a short [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) script, which can be found in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/fiedl/6294424

This script is used like this: In order to split up the data file `data.csv` into `data.Category1.csv` and `data.Category2.csv`, call:

```
# bash
ruby categorize_csv.rb --column 2 data.csv

# data.csv
# year   category   num_of_events_for_A   num_of_events_for_B
"2011";"Category1";"213";"30"
"2011";"Category2";"240";"28"
"2012";"Category1";"222";"13"
"2012";"Category2";"238";"42"
...

# data.Category1.csv
# year   category   num_of_events_for_A   num_of_events_for_B
"2011";"Category1";"213";"30"
"2012";"Category1";"222";"13"
...

# data.Category2.csv
# year   category   num_of_events_for_A   num_of_events_for_B
"2011";"Category2";"240";"28"
"2012";"Category2";"238";"42"
...
```

### Solution 1: Stacked Box Plot

**Strategy**: One data file per category. One column per stack. The bars of the histogram are plotted "manually" by using the "with boxes" argument of gnuplot.

**Upside**: Full flexibility concerning bar sizes, caps, colors, etc.

**Downside**: Bars have to be placed manually.

```
# solution1.gnuplot
reset
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 14

set datafile separator ";"

set output 'stacked_boxes.eps'

set auto x
set yrange [0:300]
set xtics 1

set style fill solid border -1

num_of_categories=2
set boxwidth 0.3/num_of_categories
dx=0.5/num_of_categories
offset=-0.1

plot 'data.Category1.csv' using ($1+offset):($3+$4) title "Category 1 A" linecolor rgb "#cc0000" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset):3 title "Category 2 B" linecolor rgb "#ff0000" with boxes, \
     'data.Category2.csv' using ($1+offset+dx):($3+$4) title "Category 2 A" linecolor rgb "#00cc00" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):3 title "Category 2 B" linecolor rgb "#00ff00" with boxes
```

The result looks like this:

[image: stacked_boxes.eps]

### Solution 2: Native Gnuplot Histogram

**Strategy**: One data file per year. One column per stack. The histogram is produced using the regular histogram mechanism of gnuplot.

**Upside**: Easier to use, since positioning has not to be done manually.

**Downside**: Since all categories are in one file, each category has the same color.

```
# solution2.gnuplot
reset
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 14

set datafile separator ";"

set output 'histo.eps'
set yrange [0:300]

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstack gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative

plot newhistogram "2011", \
       'data.2011.csv' using 3:xticlabels(2) title "A" linecolor rgb "red", \
       ''              using 4:xticlabels(2) title "B" linecolor rgb "green", \
     newhistogram "2012", \
       'data.2012.csv' using 3:xticlabels(2) title "" linecolor rgb "red", \
       ''              using 4:xticlabels(2) title "" linecolor rgb "green", \
     newhistogram "2013", \
       'data.2013.csv' using 3:xticlabels(2) title "" linecolor rgb "red", \
       ''              using 4:xticlabels(2) title "" linecolor rgb "green"
```

The result looks like this:

[image: histo.eps]

### References

- http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_time_histograms.htm
- [Gnuplot: Multiple Stacked Histograms, each group using the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483006/)
- http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node249.html

Comment: I also think, that splitting the data files is the only viable way to created those histograms. BTW: You can also accept your own answer `:)`.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, I thought I'd just wait a couple of days for maybe somebody adding a better way to do it.

Comment: Have a look at: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.8.gnu Perhaps the colors can be different for solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @fiedl! Based on your solution #1 I could come up with my own stacked/clustered histogram using more than two stacked sub categories.

Here is my code:

```
set terminal pngcairo  transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'runtimes.png'

set xtics("1" 1, "2" 2, "4" 3, "8" 4)
set yrange [0:100]

set style fill solid border -1
set key invert
set grid

num_of_ksptypes=2
set boxwidth 0.5/num_of_ksptypes
dx=0.5/num_of_ksptypes
offset=-0.12

set xlabel "threads"
set ylabel "seconds"

plot 'data1.dat' using ($1+offset):($2+$3+$4+$5) title "SDO" linecolor rgb "#006400" with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset):($3+$4+$5) title "BGM" linecolor rgb "#FFFF00" with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset):($4+$5) title "TSQR" linecolor rgb "#FFA500 " with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset):5 title "SpMV" linecolor rgb "#FF0000" with boxes, \
         'data2.dat' using ($1+offset+dx):($2+$3) title "MGS" linecolor rgb "#8B008B" with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):3 title "SpMV" linecolor rgb "#0000FF" with boxes
```

data1.dat:

```
nr  SDO  BGM  TSQR  SpMV
1   10   15   20    25
2   10   10   10    10
3   10   10   10    10
4   10   10   10    10
```

data2.dat:

```
nr  MGS  SpMV
1   23   13
2   23   13
3   23   13
4   23   13
```

the resulting plot:

[image]