# Labels per category and per bar for clustered stacked histogram

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram, stacked

Below is the gnuplot code that creates clustered stacked histogram.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 14
set datafile separator ";"
set output 'stacked_boxes.eps'
set auto x
set yrange [0:30]
set xtics 1
set style fill solid border -1
num_of_categories=2
set boxwidth 0.3/num_of_categories
dx=0.2
offset=-0.1
ddx=0.2
set key off
plot 'data.explorer0.csv' using ($1+offset):($3+$4) title "explorer0(sync)" linecolor rgb "#cc0000" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset):3 title "explorer0(wait)" linecolor rgb "#ff0000" with boxes, \
     'data.explorer1.csv' using ($1+offset+dx):($3+$4) title "explorer1(sync)" linecolor rgb "#cc0000" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):3 title "explorer1(wait" linecolor rgb "#ff0000" with boxes, \
     'data.collector0.csv' using ($1+dx+ddx):($3+$4) title "collector0(post)" linecolor rgb "#00cc00" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+dx+ddx):3 title "collector0(poll)" linecolor rgb "#00ff00" with boxes, \
     'data.collector1.csv' using ($1+dx+ddx+dx):($3+$4)  linecolor rgb "#00cc00" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+dx+ddx+dx):3 notitle linecolor rgb "#00ff00" with boxes here
```

How can I create labels for both per bar and per category?  The four bars together make a category. Let the categories be (c0, c1, c2) and the bars per category be (e0, e1, c0, c1).

The plot can be reproduced using following data files:

data.explorer0.csv:

```
#level;explorerid;sync;wait;etc
"0";"e0";"2";"2"
"2";"e0";"4";"4"
"4";"e0";"6";"6"
```

data.explorer1.csv:

```
#level;explorerid;sync;wait;etc
"0";"e1";"7";"5"
"2";"e1";"6";"10"
"4";"e1";"5";"5"
```

data.collector0.csv:

```
#level;collectorid;sync;wait;etc
"0";"c0";"2";"2"
"2";"c0";"4";"4"
"4";"c0";"6";"6"
```

data.collector1.csv:

```
#level;collectorid;sync;wait;etc
"0";"c1";"5";"5"
"2";"c1";"8";"10"
"4";"c1";"9";"5"
```

[image: stacked clustered plot]

Comment: Christoph, didn't realize I had already posted this. I was still looking at couple of links that talk about this and trying it out. Let me edit the question and add data files as well

Comment: Revised the question. Hope it is clear. Regarding the labels for the bar, they are mentioned file. But it not mandatory that we read it from the file.

Comment: Yes, now its clear :) Would it be an option for you to rearrange your data files (e.g. one data file for one category instead of one per bar-type?) That would allow you to use the `histogram` plotting style which makes thinks a lot easier. Are you on Linux? In that case this could also be done on-the-fly.

Comment: Yes. I can reformat the data. I am already using  python script to rearrange the dataset. I can modify that to output per category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the source of your script: [Gnuplot Histogram Cluster (Bar Chart) with One Line per Category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404822/2604213) :) I had thought about a solution like `solution 2` mentioned in that answer, but that doesn't work properly with the red and green colors beneath each other plus stacking the data.

The script you posted needs only very little modifications. In order to put the labels contained in the second column as xticklabels, you can use the `xtic` function in the `using` statement.

The category labels can be placed properly only explicitely with `set labels`. The x-coordinate of the label is given in units of the first x-axis, the y-value as absolute value in character units. Additionally you need to manually increase the bottom margin to make space for the category labels, which aren't accounted in the automatic margin calculations. This is done with `set bmargin 3`, which sets the bottom margin to three character heights.

Here is the modified script

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 14
set datafile separator ";"
set output 'stacked_boxes.eps'
set auto x
set yrange [0:30]
set xtics 1 nomirror
set style fill solid border -1
num_of_categories=2
set boxwidth 0.3/num_of_categories
dx=0.2
offset=-0.1
ddx=0.2
set key off

set bmargin 3
set label center "cat0" at first 0+offset/2+dx+ddx/2, char 1
set label center "cat1" at first 2+offset/2+dx+ddx/2, char 1
set label center "cat2" at first 4+offset/2+dx+ddx/2, char 1

plot 'data.explorer0.csv' using ($1+offset):($3+$4):xtic(2) title "explorer0(sync)" linecolor rgb "#cc0000" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset):3 title "explorer0(wait)" linecolor rgb "#ff0000" with boxes, \
     'data.explorer1.csv' using ($1+offset+dx):($3+$4):xtic(2) title "explorer1(sync)" linecolor rgb "#cc0000" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):3 title "explorer1(wait" linecolor rgb "#ff0000" with boxes, \
     'data.collector0.csv' using ($1+dx+ddx):($3+$4):xtic(2) title "collector0(post)" linecolor rgb "#00cc00" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+dx+ddx):3 title "collector0(poll)" linecolor rgb "#00ff00" with boxes, \
     'data.collector1.csv' using ($1+dx+ddx+dx):($3+$4):xtic(2)  linecolor rgb "#00cc00" with boxes, \
     ''                   using ($1+dx+ddx+dx):3 notitle linecolor rgb "#00ff00" with boxes
```

and its output using gnuplot 4.6.5:

[image]